# How to bind start and complete event on every ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

My question may be very basic but i am stuck on it for quite some time now.

I have an application in which i require to know the start or complete of any ajax call made through the interface whether it's a YAHOO.util.connect.asyncRequest or $.ajax() of jquery or simple XMLHttpRequest.

i have tried

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
$( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
})
```

but i think it only bind event triggering from jquery ajax function

Answer (score 1):

Like this answer [Add a "hook" to all AJAX requests on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page) you can take a look at that code and give a try.

The code hook in javascript every ajax call (not only jQuery) and let you define your own handler.

```
function addXMLRequestCallback(callback){
    var oldSend, i;
    if( XMLHttpRequest.callbacks ) {
        // we've already overridden send() so just add the callback
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.push( callback );
    } else {
        // create a callback queue
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks = [callback];
        // store the native send()
        oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
        // override the native send()
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){
            // process the callback queue
            // the xhr instance is passed into each callback but seems pretty useless
            // you can't tell what its destination is or call abort() without an error
            // so only really good for logging that a request has happened
            // I could be wrong, I hope so...
            // EDIT: I suppose you could override the onreadystatechange handler though
            for( i = 0; i < XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.length; i++ ) {
                XMLHttpRequest.callbacks[i]( this );
            }
            // call the native send()
            oldSend.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}

// e.g.
addXMLRequestCallback( function( xhr ) {
    console.log( xhr.responseText ); // (an empty string)
});
addXMLRequestCallback( function( xhr ) {
    console.dir( xhr ); // have a look if there is anything useful here
});
```