# any way to get all ajax async request url from javascript or some browser's API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to see all AJAX requests coming from a page - much like I do when using Chrome developer tools. If my code sends an `XMLRequest`, I know the URL. But if the request is not sent by my code, how can I see the request?  Is there some way to "listen" to all AJAX requests?

Comment: I made an honest attempt to rewrite the question to make it clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a "hook" to all AJAX requests on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page)

Comment: If you're allowing jQuery, you can hook the `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` global events.  Otherwise, see [this (possibly duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page).