# How to add a global listener to d3.xhr calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js

Is there any global listeners we can add for d3.xhr calls like what we have in ExtJS. Ext.Ajax.on("beforerequest", function(conn, options, eOpts){)};

I tried using 'on' as specified in https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#on

while trying

```
    d3.xhr.on("beforesend", function(request){
        console.log("inside on");
    });
```

I am getting following error.
Uncaught TypeError: d3.xhr.on is not a function

while trying below code

```
    d3.xhr(url, callback).on("beforesend", function(request){
        console.log("inside on");
    });
```

following error is thrown.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Do I have to do anything special to enable the listeners ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe `d3` offers a global hook for ajax requests.  The `xhr` object you are playing with is only for one request.  That said, you do have straight javascript [options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page)

Comment: I always use the convenience methods so I'm not familiar with the sequence of events with xhr but, reading the document you linked to I guess it would be something similar to: `d3.xhr(url).get().on("beforesend.test", function(request){ console.log("inside on")}).on("load", callback);` it's very clear in the documentation that you can't use `.on` if you specify a callback in `d3.xhr` or `xhr.get`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special, but you have to use the long form with `.get()` to use the `.on()` handlers. That is, you can't provide the callback function as the second argument to `d3.xhr()`:

```
d3.xhr("http://www.example.com") // note no callback function!
.on("beforesend", function(request){
    console.log("inside on");
})
.get(function(error, data) {
    console.log(error, data);
});
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tnuvmfjt/). Also see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750941).