# How to hook original request in webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, request

I want to hook request in webpage. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5202999/4557420) but it seems hook only XHR request.

For example, the following html dom will send a request to domain/a.jpg(Can see this request in chrome F12 Network page.)I want to hook this request and get a.jpg.

```
<img src="/a.jpg">
```

Does anyone know how to do it??? Thanks very much.

Btw, I want to get a captcha so can't get the resource by sending request by myself or it will change.

Comment: You can't do that.  Instead, you can find `<img>` tags and send your own requests.

Comment: Thanks your comment @SLaks, but i can't send request by myself bcs the image is captcha, it will change with every request.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/convert-image-data-uri-javascript

Comment: Thanks, but i want to get not only image, likes mp3 and others.