# How to retrieve data from chrome's network console tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

[This is captured from chrome's developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKMHE.png)

Based from the attached image, is it actually possible to retrieve the data in javascript/Node.js?

I've had already looked into Firefox's documentation for performance.getEntries() and it displays were performance results, none of them captured the containing data/responses .

Doing something like

```
return performance.getEntries();

or

return performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
```

will return a json formatted lists, none of them contains the data needed to be extracted.

Comment: That looks like a URL query... if you own the server/client then you should be able to get the data/response... however I'm more curious to hearing how to feed back the browsers performance to the server as a benchmark

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it is a ajax request, if you can set a hook of all the ajax request, then you can store and retrieve them. You can do this by type code on chrome's console, and the code you may need is here: [Add a "hook" to all AJAX requests on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202296/add-a-hook-to-all-ajax-requests-on-a-page). Basically it rewrite the XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send method to do what you need.